Babuska paradoxon and domain approximations for Poisson problem
I'm trying to get a better understanding of the Babuska paradox, i.e. the fact that if a domain $\omega$, that contains a curved boundary part is approximated by a sequence of polygonal domains $\omega_n$, the solution to the so called simple support boundary value problem
$$
\Delta^2 u = f \text{ in } \omega, \quad u = \Delta u + (1-\theta)\kappa\partial_n u = 0 \text{ on } \partial \omega
$$
posed on $\omega_n$ does not converge to the correct solution on $\omega$. While I get why this is happening in this case, I fail to make an easier connection:
it is sometimes stated that such domain approximations are not critical for the bending problem with clamped boundary conditions (i.e. choosing $H^2_0$ instead of $H^1_0 \cap H^2$). I know that also the classic Poisson problem with homogeneous Dirichlet BC is not critical in that regard.
Question: Can someone point out to me why exactly domain approximations are not critical for $H^2_0$ and $H^1_0$? I would also really appreciate some literature reference.
